# Can't Deploy Github Private Repo in Heroku

Tags: github, private, repo, deploying

Whenever i try to Deploy, I am getting an error saying

*Item could not be retrieved:

```
Unauthorized*
```

Why i can't deploy private repository Web Applications on Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing configuring the permissions inside your dyno for your Github account. Check this [Github integration article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration) to see how to do that.